# How to change onClick for EditTextPreference?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-preferences

i'd like to change my EditTextPreference because I need to query the contact list to recover phone numbers.

The problem is that I need to change the "onClick" method for an EditTextPreferences.

So how can I do that ?

```
        numeros = (EditTextPreference)findPreference("phone_number");
    numeros.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
            startActivityForResult(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI),REQUEST_CODE_PICK_CONTACTS);
            return true;
        }
    });
```

I did it and it worked, but the dialog stays, can we delete it ?

Comment: see if there is any method like numeros.dismiss() something like that 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/EditTextPreference.html

Comment: I found nothing like that, but I found another tip :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found, I change my EditTextPreference to a Preference and it worked.

```
numeros = findPreference("phone_number");
numeros.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
        startActivityForResult(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI),REQUEST_CODE_PICK_CONTACTS);
        return true;
    }
});
```